# Silverlight - Dynamic Layout

Tags: silverlight

I have a Silverlight application that will run out of the browser. I want the layout to resize based on the size of the window. The layout is composed of a Grid. This Grid has a Canvas which hosts a Border, and other controls. The Canvas correctly resizes as the window resizes. However, the Border control seems to be a fixed size. How do I make the Border control stretch to the width of the Canvas and resize if the Window resizes?  My code looks like the following:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition/>
    <ColumnDefinition/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <Canvas x:Name="myCanvas" Background="Lime">
    <Border Canvas.Top="77" Border="Black" BorderThickness="2">
       <TextBlock x:Name="myTextBlock" />
    </Border>
  </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are wanting the `Canvas` to be bound to the first `Grid.Column`, then you can add `RowDefinitions` and then move the Border to outside the Canvas, then the following code should work.

(Only tested in WPF)

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="77"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Canvas x:Name="myCanvas" Background="Lime" Grid.RowSpan="2">
    </Canvas>

    <Border Grid.Row="1" Border="Black" BorderThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <TextBlock x:Name="myTextBlock" Text="Happy TEXT" />
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

New stuff: `<Grid.RowDefinitions>`, `Grid.RowSpan="2"` to Canvas and `Grid.Row="1"` plus `VerticalAlignment="Top"` to Border.
Text added for testing.